# What is the best algorithm for object recognition based on its outline/edge in openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am developing an application that needs to recognize objects based on their outline in any condition. So far I can recognize the objects outline if they have a simple background, however if there is something complicated like a head or a face in the back then the algorithm fails.

I am using countures and matchShapes to do this:

```
framecp = frame
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frame = np.uint8(frame)

# Defining counturs of the frames
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(frame, 80, 255, 1)
counturs, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# res - result, ind - saved index, index - index of countures in for loop
res = 0.36
ind = 0 
index = 0

# matching every shape with the given sample to find best result.
for shape in counturs:
    if cv2.matchShapes(shape, kcounturs[1], 1, 0.0) < res:
        res = cv2.matchShapes(shape, kcounturs[1], 1, 5)
        ind = index
        print(res)
    index = index + 1

# printing result to console, drawing contours and displaying result.
cv2.drawContours(framecp, counturs, ind, (0, 0, 200), 2)
```

I have also tried applying canny on it but it didn' t work well. I even did the good old laplacian + blur + smooth to get more defined and thick edges but that was a dead end as well. At that point I decided to ditch this algorithm. I also tried a few more algorithms but this worked best for me so far. The problem is that to optimize performance I dont need to use the heavy weight algorithms like ORB or SURF or SIFT, I just need the edge of the object and then find that edge or outline in the frame.

Comment: you should ask here : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I will. It is so weird working with OpenCV. It is really easy to do the stuff but it is difficult to find which algorithm to use to maximize performance. I come from background of Web Development where I used to write thousands of lines of javascript (react) and defining my own functions and here in openCV everything you need is already in the library, the only thing I need to do is create the API (just a class) and abstract the code in there. Python is amazing, and thats coming from a guy who used to love working with C++ (OpenGL) only a month ago.

Comment: it's amazing because there is people creating those usefull packages :)